# List items CSS styles

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me what the following selector does? (the menu can be found below)

```
   ul.nav li ul {
      width: 8em;
      position: absolute;
      left: −999em;
    }
```

Does this mean:

1) select all unordered list with a class nav and target both li and ul ??

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/products/">Products</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/products/silverback/">Silverback</a></li>
      <li><a href="/products/fontdeck/">Font Deck</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


<li><a href="/services/">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/services/design/">Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services/development/">Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services/consultancy/">Consultancy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks, 
Pete

Comment: space means inside. Comma means "and". So ul in li

Comment: Get to know the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships

Answer (score 2):

select all ULs from any li inside a ul with the class "nav"

"1) select all unordered list with a class nav and target both li and ul ??"

nup selectors aren't additive (so they won't select both li and ul) - they're like a path through a tree structure.

Read it like a "breadcrumb"...

The first `ul.nav` says we're cutting down the whole html-document to only look at uls with the "nav" class on them...

Then the `li` after that says that we don't actually care about that ul.nav we're *only* looking at any `li` tags inside of them.

The final `ul` means that we don't care about the `li` tags either, we only care about a `ul` inside of any of those `li` tags

Answer (score 0):

It selects all `ul`s that are descendants of `li`s that are themselves descendants of `ul`s with the class `nav`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ul.nav li ul
```

It means: "select **ALL** ul from **ALL** li inside a `<ul class="nav">`"

This code will select:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="/products/silverback/">Silverback</a></li>
      <li><a href="/products/fontdeck/">Font Deck</a></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="/services/design/">Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services/development/">Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services/consultancy/">Consultancy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS basically put the 1st **nested** unordered list elements (ul tags) out of the document flow (position: absolute) & moves them off the page so no one sees them (left: -999em).

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are read backwards (right to left).

```
ul.nav li ul {}
```

Will apply to any:

- `ul`
- which is inside of an `li`
- which is inside of an `ul` that also has class `nav`

In the HTML below, the `ul` with `id=ThisOne` would be selected:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    Services
    <ul id="ThisOne">
      <li>Design</li>
      <li>Development</li>
      <li>Consultancy</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```